# Using useEffect cleanup function to store form values in localStorage

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using the `useEffect` cleanup function to store my formik values in localStorage. The strange part is the values stored are stale initial values and not the current form values. Here is the code:

```
  console.log(values)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // do stuff
    return function() {
      console.log(values)
      // store form data on unmount
      localStorage.setItem("formValues", JSON.stringify(values))
    };
  }, []);
```

The values logged outside the useEffect function are current, the one logged (and stored) within the cleanup function are stale initial values. I though the function would be lazily evaluated so the `values` variable would have the current value. As a shot in the dark, I also tried using a getter function for the form values. But still the old stale values. What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want cleanup just on component unmount this is what you want:

```
const valuesRef = useRef(values);

useEffect(() => {
    valuesRef.current = values;
}, [values]);

useEffect(() => {
    // do stuff
    return function() {
      console.log(valuesRef.current)
      // store form data on unmount
      localStorage.setItem("formValues", JSON.stringify(valuesRef.current))
    };
}, []);
```

Beacuase you want just cleanup and update localstorage on component unmount, you should pass empty array ([]) to useEffect. 
If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state inside the effect will always have their initial values (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). It's because each effect “belongs” to a particular render that in this case it's the first render when component is mounted.
But it might be better to update localstorage on each values change and in this case you only need to pass [values] to useEffect.

Comment: So this worked, but why is a ref necessary when the function should be lazily evaluated?

Comment: useEffect with sensivity list [] only runs 1 time at component mount also this means return function of useEffect will run 1 time at component unmount. As useEffect runs one time in compnent lifetime, so it just capture initial value of values. I've wrote another useEffect to run every time values changes and copy values to ref.

Comment: That much I understand, what I don't understand is why the cleanup function which is run once on unmount returns a stale value. I thought functions were lazily evaluated so shouldn't the `values` variable point to the current values object at the time of unmount?

Comment: If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state inside the effect will always have their initial values. each effect “belongs” to a particular render. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html.

Comment: lazily evaluated ? "No", It's because each effect “belongs” to a particular render that in this case it's the first render when component is mounted (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix this problem.

1. pass values inside the [] of useEffect.

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
    // do stuff
    return function() {
      console.log(values)
      // store form data on unmount
      localStorage.setItem("formValues", JSON.stringify(values))
    };
  }, [values]);
```

But in this way, it will save everytime values is changed
So not appropriate if you only save once when the component is unmounted

2. Second method (useRef)

```
    const formikRef = React.useRef();
    formikRef.current = useFormik({
      initialValues: ...,
      onSubmit: ...,
      validationSchema: ...
    });
    React.useEffect(() => {
      // do stuff
      return () => {
        console.log(formikRef.current.values);
        // store form data on unmount
        localStorage.setItem(
          "formValues",
          JSON.stringify(formikRef.current.values)
        );
      };
    }, []);

  const formik = formikRef.current;
```

Comment: So this worked, but why is a ref necessary when the function should be lazily evaluated?